# Use cases for categories in Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning

I started learning the concepts of machine learning.

I would like to know some of the use case scenarios for below

1. Classification
2. Regression
3. Clustering
4. Anomaly detection
5. Dimension reduction

And I would even like to know under which category the above mentioned list falls?(Is it in supervised or unsupervised or reinforcement )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### General note

You should not think about types of tasks in ML as something that has assigned label "supervised/unsupervised/...". This is not how it works. You can say that **usually** given task is solved using supervised/unsupervised learning, but this is just this. You can generate approach which has any label with any task in practise.

#### Actual answer

These parts of ML were originally well defined, but with progress in the field many of them merged, and now we have much more types of problems (like semi-supervised learning, weakly supervised classification, representation learning), so I stress that I refer to the original meaning of each

> Classification

Defined as a problem of looking for a mapping from objects to a **finite set of classes**. Usually each object has just one class (but there are generalizations to multiple ones).

Real life examples:

- Face recognition (we are given a face and answer who is it)
- Drug discovery (we are given a compound and we answer if it is a drug or not)

Type of learning: usually **supervised**

> Regression

We are looking for a mapping to a **infinite number values, with valid ordering**, for example real numbers.

Real life examples:

- Predicting for much money a user will spend in our shop based on his characteristic
- Predicting power consumption in the next month
- Predicting stock prices

Type of learning: usually **supervised**

> Clustering

Usually defined as finding a structure in data, without access to any sample of such structure (later on with many modifications such as constrained clustering, weakly supervised clustering)

Real life examples:

- Given set of images of stars, do they form some distinguishable types of stars?
- Given users activity on our website - are there distinguishable usage scenarios that we can find?

Type of learning: usually **unsupervised**

> Anomaly detection

Given a set of "normal" observations build amodel to answer "is new observation normal, or is it an anomaly?"

Real life examples:

- We have record of a valid engine parameters and need a method to alarm as that it starts to behave "weird" (even though we do not know from the past what kind of "weird" we are looking for)
- We have recordings from camera of usual people behaviour, we want method to alarm as that "something unusual is happening" (without specifing what)

Type of learning: usually **unsupervised**

> Dimension reduction

This is just a preprocessing step. Given high dimensional data we seek for a lower-dimensional representation which is usable in other tasks.

Real life examples:

- We have set of high-dimensional data (like patients records) and want to visualize it (draw on a plane)
- We have a problem of classification and our methods fail - we need to reduce dimensionality to increase scores

Type of learning: usually **unsupervised**

#### Reinforcment

None of the above **is** reinforcment learning. Reinforcment learning can be applied to any of the above, if we simply have some 'environment' saying that our method is doing 'good' or 'bad' (so instead of saying 'I want this image to be classified as cat' it only says 'I see that you classified this image as a plane, well.. it is not!').

In other words - we do any  task, but we do have humans who judge is our method good or bad, but they **do not** give as correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

classification -> dividing the data in categories where output classes are known.  -> supervised task

regression -> output data is continous -> supervised task.

clustering -> divide the data in some groups -> unsupervised task

Anomaly detection -> find out some out of the place data point from input data -> output classes labels are not required  -> unsupervised task.

Dimension reduction -> map a higher dimension input to a lower dimension input -> output classes labels are not required -> unsupervised task

Comment: I need some real time use cases

Comment: @SravaniAnnepu Real-time or  real life?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat atypical use case where [classification was used to analyze performance data in a microservice architecture](http://glennengstrand.info/software/architecture/msa/ml) and identified two issues, an environmental issue and a software bug that made the microservice more inefficient than was necessary.